# Assert that a mocked (MOQ thus DynamicProxy) event has no handlers attached

Tags: events, moq

This is quite straight forward(ish) to do is the event is 'real' as in now created by DynamicProxy, but I can't work anything out for a mocked event.

The best way to explain what I'm trying to achieve is with code, please see the comment lines in the test method:

```
using System;
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MOQTest
{
 [TestFixture]
    public class EventsMoqTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void DetachTest()
        {
            var hasEventMock = new Mock<IHasEvent>();

            using (var observer = new Observer(hasEventMock.Object))
            {
                 //Assert that hasEventMock.Object has handler attached
            }

            //Assert that hasEventMock.Object DOES NOT have handler attached
        }
    }

    public interface IHasEvent
    {
        event EventHandler AnEvent;
    }

    public class Observer : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IHasEvent _hasEvent;
        private readonly EventHandler _hasEventOnAnEvent;

        public Observer(IHasEvent hasEvent)
        {
            _hasEvent = hasEvent;

            _hasEventOnAnEvent = _hasEvent_AnEvent;
            _hasEvent.AnEvent += _hasEventOnAnEvent;
        }

        void _hasEvent_AnEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {}

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _hasEvent.AnEvent -= _hasEventOnAnEvent;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.  This isn't really a moq issue, but the way the C# event keyword works with delegates. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/572658/182895) for more information.