# Get a List of all Subscribers of an event

Tags: c#, eventhandler

hopefully this question is not too stupid ;-)

I need a list of all subscribers of an event.

for example, I got this Code:

```
Driver.PrimaryMessageReceived += Driver_PrimaryMessageReceived;
```

Now, I assume there are more that this one 'Driver_PrimaryMessageReceived' handler to the event 'PrimaryMessageReceived'

Is there a way to figure out (in runtime), which and how many subscribers to the event PrimaryMessageReveived have been subscribed?

I found this post:
[How do I get the subscribers of an event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572647/how-do-i-get-the-subscribers-of-an-event#572665)

but it wasnt very helpfull to me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And why was to linked answer not helpful to you?

Comment: because I didnt understood it...., Do I need access (full controll) to the Driver Class (in my case?)

Comment: Yes (as far as I know), `Driver.PrimaryMessageReceived.GetInvocationList` can only be called from within the `Driver` class. I don't think there is a clean solution otherwhise, but it is probably achievable using reflection