# Find out the recipients of the OnPropertyChanged event in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reverse-engineering

I am doing reverse ingineering in a project written by some one else. The GUI is made in WPF and has several windows. One class has implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and 2 properties fire the `OnPropertyChanged` event to signal the data.

My aim is to find out which control profits from this event. How can I find all controls that actually harness the information when the `OnPropertyChanged` event from the 2 properties is fired?

Looking for all references of the delegate did not lead to any results. There is no explicit registration of this event. I remember vaguely that this connection can be established in the XAML code in WPF using binding, but I don't know enough about WPF find this information on my own.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you able to use external tools for this?

Comment: @DHansen depends on the tools. What have you in mind?

Comment: https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ is what I used tremendously when developing/debugging WPF apps. Allows watching of variables, properties, templates, etc in the app at run time.

Comment: Doesn't [GetInvocationList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572647/how-do-i-get-the-subscribers-of-an-event) meet your needs? Regardless of registration by xaml or code, the invocation list will have all event handlers at the time you call it. You may need to exercise every feature of the app to make sure you see them all.

Comment: @DHansen Thank you for the link, sounds like a resourcefull tool. I will have a look at it.

Comment: @Crowcoder sounds good, as soon as I have figured out how really to use it, I can tell you whether it helps. But on the first glance it seems to catch only the explicit registrations of the event. Not the ones done by binding or context as suggested in the answers

Comment: @MongZhu, that's why you would have to exercise the entire app, registrations will likely be added and removed at runtime depending on what windows you are using, etc. Likely they will not all be present all the tmie.

Comment: @Crowcoder " You may need to exercise every feature of the app to make sure you see them all" this is actually exactly what I try to avoid. :) almost fainting when thinking of it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your two properties are named `FirstProperty` and `SecondProperty`. Just look in the XAML for binding references to them like:

```
{Binding FirstProperty}
{Binding FirstProperty, ...}
{Binding [whatever].FirstProperty, ...}
{Binding ..., Path=FirstProperty, ...}
{Binding ..., Path=[whatever].FirstProperty, ...}
```

Controls that use those bindings are the one that will get the `PropertyChanged` event. For instance, if you find:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myText", Text="{Binding FirstProperty}" />
```

this means that the above TextBox control will react to `FirstProperty` changes notified by the `PropertyChanged` event.

Comment: that sounds like a promissing approach. I have found a third variable, where  searching for the name of the property throughout the entire solution actually resulted in an entry in an XAML file. `{Binding Path=prop3`. The other 2 are not to be found still. I was doubting that someone would create properties, give them the event call and not use them. But it really seems this way.

Comment: thank you, unfortunately I can choose only one right answer, so I choose the one that came first. :)

Comment: Thank you @MongZhu. If you really want to understand how data binding and DataContext and such things work, I can only suggest my book made for WPF newcomers: https://www.amazon.com/dp/1326847996

Answer (score 1):

> How can I find all controls that actually harness the information when the OnPropertyChanged event from the 2 properties is fired?

You need to look through all XAML files where the class that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface may be used as the `DataContext` of any UIElement that has a `{Binding}` one way or another. Searching for the property names across all files is probably the easiest way.

Since the bindings are actually resolved at runtime, there is no bullet-proof way of finding all the bindings at compile-time.

Bindings may also be set up programmatically but you should be able to find these by right-clicking on the property and choose "Find All References" in Visual Studio.

Comment: thank you, especially for the `DataContext` key word. The reference search did not help in my case, but the search for the property name. Although the 2 from my question are still missing. But I get more and more convinced that they are actually not used anywhere

Comment: The OnPropertyChanged method is private isn't it?

Comment: the handler is `protected` but the event is `public` in my case

Comment: Use the "Find All References" option then?

Comment: "Looking for all references of the delegate did not lead to any results." I wrote that in my post. This was the moment where I started doubting that I see the whole picture. Could not make sense of it. That the event firing has no use in the program.

Comment: Then you are all set. The views don't bind to any event. They bind to properties.

Comment: thank you, unfortunately I can choose only one right answer, so I choose the one that came first. :)